# Tricky loop in Selenium IDE

Tags: loops, testing, selenium, selenium-ide

I am using Silenium IDE to test a website's table data. I have the Flow Control add-on, but I have a tricky loop to do.

I need to check each row of a table that its data contains certain text. The ID of each row has a different # identifying the given row. Without a loop I would do the following test:

```
assertTable    id=ctl_MainPlaceLog.1.0    071-01
assertTable    id=ctl_MainPlaceLog.2.0    071-01
assertTable    id=ctl_MainPlaceLog.3.0    071-01
assertTable    id=ctl_MainPlaceLog.4.0    071-01
etc...
```

As you can see, the row # of the IDs increase as you move down the table. Is there a way to run a loop which will check the same ID of the table but in each iteration will increase the row # WITHIN the ID? This way I can just run down the table in loop, each iteration only changing the # of the row WITHIN the same element ID.

Thank you.

Ilya

Comment: why don't you use code instead...the IDE is really just to help you to get the information you need to code

Comment: I don't know how to code!

Comment: haven't use the IDE for years, but as long as I remember it can't do what you wanted to do.

Comment: I figured it out. You can plug in variables into the id of a table

Comment: I don't use "Selenium IDE".  I use "Selenium Builder".

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code will help you do your job

```
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>i</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeElementPresent</td>
    <td>id=ctl_MainPlaceLog.${i}.0</td>
    <td>present</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>while</td>
    <td>${present}==true</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>assertText</td>
    <td>ctl_MainPlaceLog.${i}.0</td>
    <td>071-01</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>${i}+1</td>
    <td>i</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeElementPresent</td>
    <td>id=ctl_MainPlaceLog.${i}.0</td>
    <td>present</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>endWhile</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```